# MVC3 Razor Partial View does not send back to controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have a partial view that has a create button on it however it never reaches the controller once pressed. When pressed it goes to index ie /Rebate  from /Rebate/Edit/1

```
@model RMS.Models.RebateLine



@using (Html.BeginForm("Create","RebateLine",FormMethod.Post )) {
@Html.ValidationSummary(true)
<fieldset>
    <legend>RebateLine</legend>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.RebateID)
    </div>
    <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Create" />
    </p>
</fieldset>
}
```

Edit: Added controller logic

```
    public class RebateLineController : BaseController
{
   public ActionResult Create()
    {
        return View();
    } 

    //
    // POST: /RebateLine/Create

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(RebateLine rebateline)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            UnitOfWork.RebateLineRepository.Insert(rebateline);
            UnitOfWork.Save();

            return RedirectToAction("Index");  
        }

        return View(rebateline);
    }
...
  }
```

Additional Edit: /Rebate is what is shown after I click create and below is the call to the partial which is being called.

```
  @{ Html.RenderPartial("_RebateLines",Model.RebateLines.FirstOrDefault() ); }
```

Final Edit:
I have redesigned this so partials are not need to do anything but display but if someone comes up with an answer I will attempt to go back at a later date and fix it up.

Comment: can you add the code for your RebateLineController::Create action?

Comment: Sure can, though as stated never gets to it I'm sure this is something to do with how the partial is declared or how the html form inside it is.

Comment: Have you looked into what is being sent using firebug?

Comment: What is the exact url that is shown after you submit the form?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since all your code looks good. I would take a look [Glimpse](http://nuget.org/packages/Glimpse) this might help you track down the issue.

Answer (score 1):

It seems your Controller is named `RebateController`.
If that is the case then change:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Create","RebateLine",FormMethod.Post )) {
```

to

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Create","Rebate",FormMethod.Post )) {
```

**EDIT**

Create a DebugController and add a an action called: Test1.
Create the corresponding View for it. Do not use any Layout page.

Just add this markup to the body section:

```
<div>
@{Html.RenderPartial("_RebateLines",new Model.RebateLines());}
</div>
```

Run the project in debug mode and visit the /debug/test1 url.
Place a breakpoint in your RebatteLines::Create action.
Hit the submit button.
Breakpoint must be hit.
If it is hit that means that there is something in the page where you are calling Html.RenderPartial that is preventing the form from submitting to the expected url, probably some javascript. Might even be in your layout.
Confirm if test I mention above runs as expected.

Comment: I have two separate controllers one called rebate and one called rebate line.

Comment: There is nothing wrong in your code. It really should work. Did you try setting a breakpoint in your Create action? Are you 100% sure it is not being called?

Comment: Show us the code where you render your Partial view? Are you sure you are rendering the correct one?

Comment: code added and yes it correctly populates with the default information I am providing (the default information conforms to all model rules)

Comment: What you've shown is all ok. Problem must be in the code you have not shown. Maybe you have some js code intercepting the submit and posting to another url?

Answer (score 0):

You are using a controller named "RebateLineController" and a ActionResult "Create". But you have mentioned the url as "/Rebate/Edit/1". Is the url correct?

And from your code:

```
if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        UnitOfWork.RebateLineRepository.Insert(rebateline);
        UnitOfWork.Save();

        return RedirectToAction("Index");  
    }
```

it is clear that if the modelstate is valid, the page will be redirected to "Index" as you have given:

```
return RedirectToAction("Index");
```

Am I correct? This is what I can assume from your code.

Regards..
Sunil

Comment: Partial view on the page deaqls with rebate line the url if fine.

Answer (score -1):

Try using

```
@Html.RenderAction("Create", "RebateLines", new { id = Model.RebateLines.FirstOrDefault().RebateID })
```

And change your controller as below:

```
public class RebateLineController : BaseController
{
   public ActionResult Create(int id)
    {
      return View();
    } 

//
// POST: /RebateLine/Create

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(int id,RebateLine rebateline)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        UnitOfWork.RebateLineRepository.Insert(rebateline);
        UnitOfWork.Save();

        return RedirectToAction("Index");  
    }

    return View(rebateline);
}
...
}
```

Hope it helps..

Mark as answer if useful.